# I get 'Error: Index exceeds matrix dimensions' altough indices do not exceed the dimensions

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, oop

I know similar questions have been asked a million times before but I checked many pages and still could't find a proper solution to my problem. So here is my question:

(I am writing the code in MATLAB. I am not giving the whole code because it is super long, complex and irrelevant.)

I created an object called `OpO` from a certain class in my main file. And in that class there is a two dimensional array of zeros, namely `TotMargin`. Let's say it has dimensions of A and B. Later, I created a function which takes this object as an input and uses it in an equation like:

```
Half = OpO.Margin(t,1) + OpO.TotMargin(t+1,Next) - StartUpCost(t);
```

Both `t+1<A` and `Next<B` holds, and when I write the actual values of these variables in the command window (`OpO.TotMargin(8761,5)`), I get the answer '0', which is exactly what I expect to see. I am sure that the problem is related with that array, because when I delete that array from the equation, I do not get any errors in this line. Also when I replace `Next` with any number greater than 1, I still get the same error. Whereas, with the value 1, I do not get any errors.

I checked whether there is another array or class with the same name which may lead to confusion for MATLAB. But, again, there is none.

Does anyone have any idea about what may be wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of t at the time error occurred? Try using "dbstop if error" to stop in debugger when the error happens.

Comment: Let me assure you that your title is wrong. If you are getting an "index exceeds matrix dimensions" error then the index will be exceeding the matrix dimensions. Careful that `t` doesn't start at 0, and that your loop ends at `A-1` so that `t+1` is valid. As Navan says, debug your code where the error is caused and check all of the dimensions, it sounds like your problem is in the assumptions you are making. Other than that we will be hard pushed to help you without the code which generates and accesses the matrices in question.

Comment: @Wolfie, yes you are right, maybe my title wasn't very bright:) But i do use a debugger already and i know for sure that this is the line with the problem. To be exact, at the time when the error happens the value of my variables are Next = 5, and t = 8760. TotMargin array is an array with dimensions of 8761x56 and the array consists of zeroes. I was wondering howcome  that I obtain a corresponding value for each of the three components of 'Half' when I wrote them in the command line with the actual values of the variables at the time when the error occurs AND i still can get this error :/

Comment: If you can successfully evaluate `OpO.Margin(t,1)`,  `OpO.TotMargin(t+1,Next)` and `StartUpCost(t)` individually then this line is not the issue! You must post more code for this to be diagnosed, it's currently impossible as your diagnosis doesn't match your symptoms.